# TensorFlow 1.5.0 run with DataLab raise AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'length' while attempting to use embedding_column

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-datalab

Attempt to use embedding_column in a way:

from tensorflow.contrib import layers //
output = layers.embedding_column(input, 10, combiner='sum', max_norm=None)

result in error message:

{
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column.py", line 1302, in embedding_column
    max_norm=max_norm, trainable=trainable)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column.py", line 1046, in **new**
    stddev = 1 / math.sqrt(sparse_id_column.length)
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'length'
}

"input" is a column of integer values. Any ideas how to handle that?

Comment: WARNING:tensorflow:The default stddev value of initializer will change from "1/sqrt(vocab_size)" to "1/sqrt(dimension)" after 2017/02/25. Does this mean that it was not changed in TF 1.5.0 as it was planned??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your "input" argument is a Tensor while it should be a [feature column](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/feature_columns) and, more specifically, a sparse column created by [`sparse_column_with_*` or `weighted_sparse_column`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.layers#Feature_columns) functions.